# Oauth 2.0 authentication grant-type: password

Tags: php, authentication, passwords

I am using oauth2.0 to secure my api endpoints, this is my first implementation of this system so I am so confused about it, I know how I can get access token using grant-type:password, but I don't how I can register a new user and store the client_secret in database and verify that the password that I use to get the access_token is the same that the user use first time in registration form.
I am using php, symfony framework, fosuserbundle and oauthserverbundle for security.

Comment: The application is the client, a user is the person using the application. The client secret has nothing to do with the user. A _client_ has a client id (and depending on the grant type flow a secret). The password grant type is a _user_ flow. For this flow the client sends the client_id, the username and the password (and optionally the client secret). So you can register one client (being your app) and multiple users that use the app.

Comment: thank you somuch sir.